# Find number of characters matching pattern in XSLT 1

Tags: regex, xslt

I need to make an  statement where the test pass if there is just one asterisk in a string from the source document.

Thus, something like

```
<xslt:if test="count(find('\*', @myAttribute)) = 1)>
    There is one asterisk in myAttribute
</xslt:if>
```

I need the functionality for XSLT 1, but answers for XSLT 2 will be appreciated as well, but won't get acceptance unless its impossible in XSLT 1.

Comment: Maybe something like stringlength(replace('[^\*]', '', @myAttribute)) == 1 would work?

Comment: Ended up using this rule:
<xsl:if test="translate(@myAttribute, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\.', '') = '*'"> single asterisk... </xsl:if>
If you have better answers, please post them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, we can do it by removing all asterisks using `translate` and comparing the length:

```
string-length(@myAttribute) - string-length(translate(@myAttribute, '*', '')) = 1
```

In XPath 2.0, I'd probably do this:

```
count(string-to-codepoints(@myAttribute)[. = string-to-codepoints('*')]) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that should work in XPath 1.0:

```
contains(@myAttribute, '*') and not(contains(substring-after(@myAttribute, '*'), '*'))
```

Comment: Nice answer. It looks a bit more specific than the question asks, but actually works well in my case, since the asterisk would always end the phrase.
thanks, but the xpath 2 answer is slightly better.